# binary search in array with all elements equal

Tags: time-complexity, binary-search

I got a problem with binary search. What I am doing is following:-

*Given a sorted array arr[ ] and a number x counts the occurence of x in arr[ ] the function to implement this logic in an efficient way would take????*

The answer is `O(log(n))` as I use binary search,but what is I have an array arr[] with all elements equal,then I will not be able to get my answer in `O(log(n))` time. It will take O(n) time.

Now I claim that an efficient algorithm to implement this problem takes `O(n)` time. Does my claim holds??

Answer (score 0):

Well, the efficient algorithm is:

1. find the index of the first occurrence of x.
2. find the index of the last occurrence of x.
3. the answer is (2) - (1) + 1

And that's still O(log n).